# Errors from official angular script

Tags: angular, angular-material, phpstorm

I have copied the following code from https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview:

```
visible: boolean = true;
selectable: boolean = true;
removable: boolean = true;
addOnBlur: boolean = true;

// Enter, comma
separatorKeysCodes = [ENTER, COMMA];

fruits = [
  { name: 'Lemon' },
  { name: 'Lime' },
  { name: 'Apple' },
];


add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
  let input = event.input;
  let value = event.value;

  // Add our fruit
  if ((value || '').trim()) {
      this.fruits.push({ name: value.trim() });
  }

  // Reset the input value
  if (input) {
      input.value = '';
  }
}

remove(fruit: any): void {
  let index = this.fruits.indexOf(fruit);

  if (index >= 0) {
      this.fruits.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

But I get following errors:

> - TSLint: Type boolean trivially inferred from a boolean literal,    remove type annotation (no-inferrable-types)
> - Unused field visible
> - TSLint: Identifier 'value' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'let'. (prefer-const)

Why am I getting those errors? I don't think that it's Angulars fault. So I must be doing something wrong?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These aren't "errors" from official Angular docs. They are warnings from the typescript linter. Angular CLI comes bundled with TSLint, which is a package that checks after your code and gives you warnings so you can keep your code clean and respect standards.

> - TSLint: Type boolean trivially inferred from a boolean literal,    remove type annotation (no-inferrable-types)

When declaring a variable, if you initialize it there is no need to specify a type since typescript can deduce it from the specified value.

```
let myVar = true; // myVar is of inferred boolean type
```

> - Unused field visible

You variable *visible* is declared but never used. It's a hint to maybe just remove it from your code.

> - TSLint: Identifier 'value' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'let'. (prefer-const)

If you never reassign a value to a variable, use const instead of let. A *const* variable will hold a value while protecting it from being changed.

Just use the recommended modifications:

```
selectable = true;
removable = true;
addOnBlur =true;

// Enter, comma
separatorKeysCodes = [ENTER, COMMA];

fruits = [
  { name: 'Lemon' },
  { name: 'Lime' },
  { name: 'Apple' },
];


add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
  let input = event.input;
  const value = event.value;

  // Add our fruit
  if ((value || '').trim()) {
      this.fruits.push({ name: value.trim() });
  }

  // Reset the input value
  if (input) {
      input.value = '';
  }
}

remove(fruit: any): void {
  let index = this.fruits.indexOf(fruit);

  if (index >= 0) {
      this.fruits.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: If Angular CLI comes bundled with TSLint, then I don't understand why they wouldn't clean their code with no warnings. But that helped me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Those are linting errors , in other words they don't produce bugs, but they exist because the code is not according the TSlint style guide, it's the same for example when you are using `standard js` linter and you are placing `;` the linter will underline the `;` as errors.

Answer (score 1):

Its because TSLint is enabled for your IDE

**TSLint: Type boolean trivially inferred from a boolean literal, remove type annotation (no-inferrable-types)**

In ts type is inferable - you don't need to explicitly mention :boolean when you assign a boolean value. Change as below

```
visible = true;
selectable = true;
removable = true;
addOnBlur = true;
```

**Unused field visible**

Your aren't using *visible* anywhere in the code

**TSLint: Identifier 'value' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'let'. (prefer-const)**

when you aren't reassigning the variable you define it as const instead of let

```
const value = event.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have an option to disable this warning inside the tslint.json

`"no-inferrable-types": [true, "ignore-params"]` **to** `"no-inferrable-types": [false, "ignore-params"]`